How do I access a field from the main query inside a sub query in mySQL?
I have 3 tables: products, product_options and product_option_choices. Products can have multiple options, options can have multiple choices.
Choices can adjust the main product price (choice_price_adjust field).
What I'm trying to do is fetch the products and have a field returned on each product that is the maximum possible adjustment value and the minimum possible adjustment value so I know the range of prices this product can be sold at.
This is what I have so far but I seem unable to reference the prod_id field (or even an alias) of the products table within the subquery.
If I give a specific product id in place of pid it works but obviously I want to subquery running based on each individual product.
I'm also open to suggestions on how to improve the whole query without needing to find a solution to this particular issue.
SELECT *, p.prod_id as pid,
    (SELECT SUM(y.min) as min_total 
     FROM (
        SELECT x.min as min 
        FROM (
            SELECT product_option_choices.prod_op_id as op_id, MIN(choice_price_adjust) as min
            FROM product_option_choices
            WHERE prod_id = pid
            GROUP BY product_option_choices.prod_op_id
        ) x
        GROUP BY x.op_id
    ) y) as choices_min_price
FROM products p

--
EDIT to clarify data and expected results.
The database structure (simplified to only relevant test data and I haven't added FKs) is as follows:
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `prod_id` int(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(16) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `products` (`prod_id`, `product_name`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 'Product 1', 1000),
(2, 'Product 2', 2000);

CREATE TABLE `product_options` (
  `prod_op_id` int(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `prod_op_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `prod_id` int(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `product_options` (`prod_op_id`, `prod_op_name`, `prod_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Color', 1),
(2, 'Size', 1),
(3, 'Grade', 1),
(4, 'Direction', 2),
(5, 'Smell', 2),
(6, 'Origin', 2);

CREATE TABLE `product_option_choices` (
  `choice_id` int(16) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `prod_op_id` int(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `prod_id` int(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `choice_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `choice_price_adjust` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `product_option_choices` (`choice_id`, `prod_op_id`, `prod_id`, `choice_name`, `choice_price_adjust`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'Purple', 100),
(2, 1, 1, 'Orange', -500),
(3, 2, 1, 'Small', -300),
(4, 2, 1, 'Large', 400),
(5, 3, 1, 'A', 900),
(6, 3, 1, 'B', 100),
(7, 4, 2, 'Up', 200),
(8, 4, 2, 'Down', -200),
(9, 5, 2, 'Vanilla', -150),
(10, 5, 2, 'Sandlewood', 0),
(11, 6, 2, 'Afica', 0),
(12, 6, 2, 'Norway', 700);

ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`prod_id`);

ALTER TABLE `product_options`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`prod_op_id`);

ALTER TABLE `product_option_choices`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`choice_id`);

Each product has its own set of options. Each of those options has their own set of choices. In the front end, one choice per option can be selected by users (a selection for each option is required).
What I'm trying to have returned by the query is a row for each product with the product table data (product_name, price) but also a calculated column for both the maximum and minimum possible totals for 'choice_price_adjust'.
For example, with product 1 the user has to select a value for Color, Size and Grade. They cannot select a value for Direction, Smell or Origin because those options are for product 2.
The user has a choice of: Purple and Orange for Color; Small and Large for Size; A and B for Grade. I only added 2 in each but there can be 1 or more, it is not always 2 choices.
So, for Product 1's returned row I would want the query to look at the available values for Color (Purple and Orange). It then grabs the lowest value within those choices as the lowest_value (in this case, Orange is lower at -500 so that's the lowest_value). It also grabs the highest value within those choices (100 in this case from Purple) and that's the highest_value. Same with Size (in this case, -300 is lowest, 400 is highest). Same for Grade (100 is lowest, 900 is highest). All other choices and options are irrelevant because they do NOT have a prod_id value of 1 (Product 1).
I'd then like the total of the lowest_value numbers (as min_total) and the total of the highest_value numbers (as max_total) to be added as a column in the product row that gets returned along with prod_id, product_name and price for each product. In the above case, min_total would be -700 (-500 + -300 + 100). max_total would be 1,400 (100 + 400 + 900)
My latest attempt based on feedback was to add the subquery to the FROM and consider JOINs but it's still not right as it is doing the SUM on ALL choices and not the subset I'm trying to pick for each product. I'm using the test data for this now:
SELECT p.prod_id, p.product_name, p.price, SUM(x.min_val) as min_total, SUM(x.max_val) as max_total

FROM products p, (
    SELECT
    poc.prod_id,
    poc.choice_id,
    MIN(poc.choice_price_adjust) as min_val,
    MAX(poc.choice_price_adjust) as max_val
FROM product_option_choices poc
LEFT JOIN product_options po on(po.prod_op_id = poc.prod_op_id)
LEFT JOIN products p2 on(p2.prod_id = poc.prod_id)
GROUP BY poc.choice_id
) x
GROUP BY p.prod_id;

When I try to add WHERE p2.prod_id = p.prod_id I'm told p.prod_id is an unknown column. I thought I could use this as it's only within a single subquery now? Or is this because of the order in which subqueries run based on which part of the main query they are in?

You can't. Correlated subqueries can only refer to columns one level higher.

In general, try to use joins rather than correlated subqueries.

sounds like you might want to use a CTE

You also can't refer to a column alias in a correlated subquery. You'd need WHERE prod_id = p.prod_id.

why do you think you need three levels to get that sum(min ? a single query would do just fine.

What's the point of GROUP BY x.op_id? You have no aggregation functions in that subquery. The query nested inside it is already grouped by the same column.

@JorgeCampos you're right, I don't know why I added the middle one - I've removed that but I can't see how I could do it in one. This is the first time I'm using subqueries and I think I'm trying to do too much at once and just getting confused about what I'm asking the database for.

you can just do: SELECT prod_id, prod_op_id as op_id, sum(MIN(choice_price_adjust)) as minTotal ... group by prod_id, prod_op_id put it on the from section as a subquery table (as suggested by Barmar) and join with the prod_id = pid that should do it for you

See JOIN LATERAL

@JorgeCampos
I’m trying that but I get “invalid use of group function” when I try to use MIN/MAX within the SUM function.

Sorry, yes, we can't nest those functions, see this version https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/14772

ALTERNATIVE ANSWER:
Since there were some missunderstandings about the expected result and since it seams that the result should depend on user provided selection of product id and/or option id here is the answer where the resultset and lowest/largest values depend on user's selections.
Sample data and this code could be found and played with in the fiddle here.
/* 
Try to change the values of the variables @usr_prod_id And @usr_prod_op_id
The variables here play the role of user selections for fetching the data

VARIABLES SETTINGS:
 1. If both ids are 0 or Null - result is all products  with TOTAL values
 2. If product id = 0 or Null and option id > 0 result is selected option with option values 
 3, If product id > 0 And option id = 0 or Null result is selected product with all options and option values
 4. If product id > 0 And option id > 0 result is selected option with option values (same as 2.) 
 5. If any id is less then 0 - there will be no rows selected
*/

SET @usr_prod_id = 0, 
    @usr_prod_op_id = 0;

WITH
  usr_selection as
    ( Select  Case When Coalesce(@usr_prod_id, 0) = 0 And 
                        Coalesce(@usr_prod_op_id , 0) = 0 
                   Then 'PRODS'
                   When Coalesce(@usr_prod_id, 0) = 0 And 
                        Coalesce(@usr_prod_op_id , 0) > 0 
                   Then 'OPTS'
                   When Coalesce(@usr_prod_id, 0) > 0 And 
                        Coalesce(@usr_prod_op_id , 0) = 0 
                   Then 'OPTS'
                   When Coalesce(@usr_prod_id, 0) > 0 And
                        Coalesce(@usr_prod_op_id , 0) > 0
                   Then 'OPTS'
              Else 'ERROR'
              End as flag
   ), 
  grid AS
    ( Select     usr.flag, p.prod_id, p.product_name, p.price, 
                 po.prod_op_id, po.prod_op_name, 
                 poc.choice_name, poc.choice_price_adjust
      From       product_options po
      Inner Join usr_selection usr ON( usr.flag != 'ERROR' )
      Left Join  product_option_choices poc ON(poc.prod_id = po.prod_id And poc.prod_op_id = po.prod_op_id)
      Left Join  products p ON(p.prod_id = po.prod_id)  
   ),
  adjustments as
   ( Select    flag, prod_id, product_name, price, prod_op_id, prod_op_name, 
               Min(choice_price_adjust) as lowest_price_adjust, 
               Max(choice_price_adjust) as largest_price_adjust
     From      grid
     Group By  flag, prod_id, product_name, prod_op_id, prod_op_name, price
   )
Select Distinct    
          a.prod_id, a.product_name, a.price,  
          Case When flag = 'PRODS' 
               Then Sum(a.lowest_price_adjust) 
                        Over(Partition By prod_id)  
               When flag = 'OPTS'
               Then lowest_price_adjust
          End as lowest,
          Case When flag = 'PRODS' 
               Then Sum(a.largest_price_adjust) 
                        Over(Partition By prod_id)  
               When flag = 'OPTS'
               Then largest_price_adjust
          End as largest, 
          Case When flag = 'PRODS' Then Concat('Total - ', a.product_name)
               When flag = 'OPTS'  Then Concat('Option - ', a.prod_op_name)
          End as source_of_values
From      adjustments a
Where     a.prod_id = Case When Coalesce(@usr_prod_id, 0) > 0 
                           Then @usr_prod_id 
                      Else a.prod_id 
                      End 
      And 
          a.prod_op_id = Case When Coalesce(@usr_prod_op_id, 0) > 0 
                              Then @usr_prod_op_id 
                         Else a.prod_op_id
                         End
Order By  prod_id, product_name

/*    R e s u l t :    ( for @usr_prod_id = 0 And @usr_prod_op_id = 0 )
prod_id  product_name    price  lowest  largest  source_of_values
-------  -------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------------
      1  Product 1        1000    -700     1400  Total - Product 1
      2  Product 2        2000    -350      900  Total - Product 2      */

/*    R e s u l t :    ( for @usr_prod_id = 2 And @usr_prod_op_id = 0 )
prod_id  product_name    price  lowest  largest  source_of_values
-------  -------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------------
      2  Product 2        2000    -200      200  Option - Direction
      2  Product 2        2000    -150        0  Option - Smell
      2  Product 2        2000       0      700  Option - Origin

/*    R e s u l t :    ( for @usr_prod_id = 0 And @usr_prod_op_id = 3 )
prod_id  product_name    price  lowest  largest  source_of_values
-------  -------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------------
      1  Product 1      1000       100      900  Option - Grade

This solution reflects the way that I see the problem and possible solution, The code could be furtheremore adjusted and/or fine tuned if I got something wrong. What it can't do is to result with variable number of columns. The number of columns and their datatypes must be exact. If there is a need to get the result in some cases with 6 columns and in the other 4 (or 8) columns then there should be another SQL statement,

This is also excellent. I can definitely adapt it to my needs and I understand the limitations you've mentioned. My final question is: could you recommend a good learning resource for advanced SQL like this? This whole exercise has shown me that my SQL knowledge is very much lacking for developing complex queries.

@twistedpixel I realy do hope this could help you. About the learning, in my opinion, the best teacher is work itself. When you deal with problems day after day - you use every possible source to get it done and, arguably, one of the very, very best  is right here. I, myself, learned the most right here at StackOverflow solving problems and understanding issues as they pop up. I work with Oracle most of the time for 33 years now and there are a fair few lessons learned along the way.

@twistedpixel Get what ever you can from any source you find  - and work. Every problem solved  is something that builds you as a profesional raising your selfconfidence and making you more and more competent and more competitive. This portal is on top of it as a helping hand.

With your sample data provided you should consider to do it step by step using two ctes ...
Step 1.
... create a cte (grid) collecting all the products, options and choices data in the same row
WITH
  grid AS
    ( Select     p.prod_id, p.product_name, p.price, 
                 po.prod_op_name, 
                 poc.choice_name, poc.choice_price_adjust
      From       product_options po
      Left Join  product_option_choices poc ON(poc.prod_id = po.prod_id And poc.prod_op_id = po.prod_op_id)
      Left Join  products p ON(p.prod_id = po.prod_id)  
   ), 

Step 2.
... create second cte to get lowest and largest price adjustments per product and option
  adjustments as
   ( Select    prod_id, product_name, price, prod_op_name, 
               Min(choice_price_adjust) as lowest_price_adjust, 
               Max(choice_price_adjust) as largest_price_adjust
     From      grid
     Group By  prod_id, product_name, prod_op_name, price
   )

Step 3.
... main sql with all the data from above and calculated total lowest and largest price adjustments per product
--      M a i n    S Q L :
Select    a.*, 
          Sum(a.lowest_price_adjust) Over(Partition By prod_id) as total_product_lowest, 
          Sum(a.largest_price_adjust) Over(Partition By prod_id) as total_product_largest
From      adjustments a
Order By  prod_id, product_name, prod_op_name

/*
prod_id product_name    price   prod_op_name    lowest_price_adjust largest_price_adjust     total_product_lowest    total_product_largest
------- ------------  -------   --------------   ------------------- --------------------    --------------------    ---------------------
1   Product 1            1000   Color                           -500                  100                    -700                     1400
1   Product 1            1000   Grade                            100                  900                    -700                     1400
1   Product 1            1000   Size                            -300                  400                    -700                     1400
2   Product 2            2000   Direction                       -200                  200                    -350                      900
2   Product 2            2000   Origin                             0                  700                    -350                      900
2   Product 2            2000   Smell                           -150                    0                    -350                      900      */

Now you have the resultset for all the products/options/choices containing Min/Max values per product and option as well as total lowest and total largest price adjustments per product. So, if you want just one option - filter it in Main SQL's WHERE clause:
--    M  a i n   S Q L : 
Select    ... ... ...
From      adjustments a
WHERE     a.prod_op_name = 'Size'
... ... ...

This resultset can easily be filtered by user provided selection of product and option combination. The combinations could be offered to the users as a kind of list of legit values derived from the collected data (the 1st cte grid) or selecting the combinations directly from your tables. Here are the posible user selections from grid cte:
/* LIST OF POSSIBLE USER SELECTION */
WITH
  grid AS
    ( Select     p.prod_id, p.product_name, p.price, 
                 po.prod_op_name, 
                 poc.choice_name, poc.choice_price_adjust
      From       product_options po
      Left Join  product_option_choices poc ON(poc.prod_id = po.prod_id And poc.prod_op_id = po.prod_op_id)
      Left Join  products p ON(p.prod_id = po.prod_id)  
   )
Select   product_name, prod_op_name
From     grid
Group By product_name, prod_op_name
Order By product_name, prod_op_name 

/*    R e s u l t :
product_name    prod_op_name
------------    ------------
Product 1       Color
Product 1       Grade
Product 1       Size
Product 2       Direction
Product 2       Origin
Product 2       Smell           */

See the fiddle here (with results for all steps).

I see what you're doing but it doesn't quite work for my case. Options are unique to products so I need the SUM of all the MIN values but ONLY where the option and choice are for the relevant product_id. I've tried to modify your example with the comment suggestions above (your code as a subquery table in the main query FROM) and SUMMing the min_value and max_value cols but the value is then the same for every product and includes ALL min_value and ALL max_value numbers SUMmed, not just the relevant ones for that product.

@twistedpixel Provide some sample data, explain te logic for data provided and telll us the expected result for the sample data. It could be just two products and few optiions and choices. The answer above is nothing more but blind guessing for there are nothing that we could help with.  The code alone is not sufficient.

Thanks, I've updated the original question with hopefully enough test data and explanation to describe what I'm trying to achieve here and also my latest attempt and results.

@twistedpixel Just posted the answer using your sample data. Please check it out with your actual data.

This is fantastic thank you - and I think I just about follow what's going on: you're essentially creating "on the fly" temporary tables to make it easier to pick the data you want. The only issue is that selecting from the temporary "adjustments" table results in a row for every option. This works great for working out full product configurations but in the case of using these temporary tables to produce a single (paged) product list, obviously I only want a single row for each product. Is it safe to use DISTINCT on results from these temporary tables to achieve that?

@twistedpixel To fetch one row you just need to add WHERE clause to the Main SQL code whiich will filter the resultset to just row that the user has selected. Like: WHERE prod_op_name = 'size' - this will fetch just that row...

Sorry I don't think I made myself clear. What I meant was that for example, 3 of more or less the same row are returned for each product if you look at the results. What I meant was to return only 1 of those rows but FOR EACH PRODUCT in a larger query where I perhaps have a "WHERE category = 5" that should return all products in the category with ID of 5. Currently the list returns 1 row for each option available to that product. That's why I suggested DISTINCT but I don't think it's the right way. Is there a better way to say "return only rows with a unique value in a particular column"?

@twistedpixel This I don't understand. I could, though, if you showed us the expected result with the sample data and logic.. Please, be specific and post the result you want if producf 1 and option Size are selected. OR Product 2 and option Smell.. Or whatever specific combination you want.   Show the parameters passed to query snd resulting table when run against the data provided.

@twistedpixel BTW. What is category? Hope it is option. There were no categories untill your last comment...

Maybe I’m not being clear. You don’t need to worry about category, it is only in my real products table, it was just an example. I will try to be clear. On a page listing all products, I do not need to know all different configurations (although very useful elsewhere!), I only need for each product minimum and maximum configuration price, which this table provides. The issue is if I fetch products from the final table here, I will get 3 of product 1 when I only need 1.

For example, if you look at your step 3 output, all 3 rows for product 1 are useful on product 1’s individual product page. But on a page listing many products, I do not need each option min and max, only the total min and total max (last 2 columns) along with the main product data (name, price). Does that make sense? A single row returned for product 1 that has total_product_lowest and total_product_largest. Otherwise if all 3 rows return for each product, the product will be duplicated 3 times on the page when looped through the array.

Your answer is excellent and has really helped me understand CTE and GROUP BY. What I am asking is simply in addition so I can use the CTE to get a list of products (with the calculated columns included).

@twistedpixel Steo 3: Main SQL: Instead of Select a.* put this  - Select Distinct a.prod_id, a.product_name, a.price,  -  and from Order By remove prod_op_name. Result will be one row per product with id, name, price and two total columns.

@twistedpixel You can see the fiddle at https://dbfiddle.uk/n6s59Tko .

@twistedpixel Just posted an alternative new answer. Please check it out and see if it suits you.
